# Manjaro GNOME screen brightness doesn't change

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, manjaro

I'm using Asus Zenbook Pro Duo, Intel Core i7 and Nvidia RTX 2060.

```
$ ls /sys/class/backlight
intel_backlight
```

When I change the brightness from the keyboard, it shows values going up and down, but it doesn't actually reflect in the brightness levels. It always stays full bright.

The following values change from keyboard interaction, but don't change screen brightness.

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
14496
```

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106M [GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile] driver: nvidia v: 455.38 
           Device-3: IMC Networks USB2.0 HD IR UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
           Display: x11 server: X.org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting,nvidia resolution: <xdpyinfo missing> 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.1
```

Comment: shifted to windows, all works fine :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.

I resolved changing the backlight on the main display by installing the newest experimental Linux kernel `5.14.rc3.d` (you can do so through the Manjaro Settings Manager).

So far I have only been able to change the brightness (not backlight) of the secondary display by installing `icc-brightness-gnome-git` from the AUR. If anyone has some input as to how to change the backlight of the secondary display please reply below.

Reboot to apply the changes.

Comment: The issue was with original screenpad software, when I shifted back to windows, even there it wasn't working. So I just updated software on windows. It works. Not sure how software update on windows affects everywhere

Comment: Software updates in Windows should not do anything in Linux.